# Make Add Printer window resizable or larger in Windows

Tags: windows-7, printer

When selecting drivers for a printer using Windows 7's Add Printer wizard, the window cannot be re-sized or maximized.  When scrolling through hundreds of drivers for different models of printers it would be nice to be able to re-size this.

Is there a quick hack to force this particular window to be able to be re-sized for my convenience?

Comment: I concur; this has aggravated me as well over the years (it's been like that since before Windows 7). :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a portable utility called [ResizeEnable](http://www.digitallis.co.uk/pc/downloads.html) that's intended for making non-resizable windows resizable.  It was written a while back, but it still works under Window 7.

You may have to run it "as administrator" depending on the dialog Window.  I also found that you have to move the window around a little before it will hook it and allow you to resize.

The inner control resizing is a little hit or miss but it may do the trick for you.

Comment: Good tool.  I can tell when it hooks and I am able to use it, however, the particular "Add Printer" window that I wanted to re-size was unresponsive to this program!  Thanks anyway, upvoted for still being a good answer.